# Ant Design TreeSelect map data from API to title value keys

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, mapping, antd

I am trying to populate a [Tree Select in ANT Design](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/) from API, the API Response type is so

```
projectData = ProjectData[];

export type ProjectData = {
    key?: number;
    projectId: number;
    projectName: string;
    description: string;
    level: number;
    parent: string;
    parentId: number;
    children: ProjectData[];
};
```

for [TreeSelect](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/) I can't find an option to set `title` to `projectName` and `value` to `projectId`

Tree select takes `treeData` values in this format

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: 'Node1',
    value: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Child Node1',
        value: '0-0-1',
      },
      {
        title: 'Child Node2',
        value: '0-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Node2',
    value: '0-1',
  },
];
```

For example if I am using a a [Cascader](https://ant.design/components/cascader/) in ant design I can set the mapping with the `fieldNames` prop like so

`fieldNames={{ label: 'projectName', value: 'projectId', children: 'children' }}`

is it possible at all to do something like this with TreeSelect?

I have a `ProjectData[]` as mentioned above and I need to generate a tree select using that data. What is the best way?

Now If I use Cascader I can only select the Last(deepest) entry and not a node which is a parent. Thus I have to use Treeselect and Can't figure out how to map it properly.

------- Edit -----------

Added a sample of data with implementation of cascader and treeselect on [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tree-select-do2wh?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: When you get the `projectData`, is is flat or nested? Or both?--looks like it has both an array of `children` and a `parentId`. I can help you map this but I'm not sure if we should use the flat `treeDataSimpleMode` format or the nested `treeData` format.

Comment: Hold up...sounds like we don't even need to map! "It is possible to replace the default id and pId keys by providing object to treeDataSimpleMode".

Comment: @LindaPaiste i added an example with sample data on [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-tree-select-do2wh?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading the docs, it seems like you can do this through the prop `treeDataSimpleMode`.  This would change the expected format of the `treeData` from nested objects with `children` to a flat array where each object has its own `id` and a parent id `pId`.  It also appears that we can specify the property names for `id` and `pId` which is exactly what you want.  We can change `treeNodeLabelProp` from `"label"` to `"projectName"` and `treeNodeFilterProp` from `"value"` to `"projectId"`.

So it seems like this might be all you need:

```
const MyTree = ({projectData}: {projectData: ProjectData[]}) => {
  return (
    <TreeSelect
      treeData={projectData}
      treeDataSimpleMode={{
        id: 'projectId',
        pId: 'parentId',
        //rootPId can be set too
      }}
      treeNodeLabelProp="projectName"
      treeNodeFilterProp="projectId"
    />
  )
```

I can't really test this out without sample data so let me know if you get any errors.

Note that the typings in the antd package are not strict enough to detect changes in the formatting.  The `DataNode` interface makes all of the expected properties optional and has a string index signature to allow for any custom properties.

```
export interface DataNode {
    value?: RawValueType;
    title?: React.ReactNode;
    label?: React.ReactNode;
    key?: Key;
    disabled?: boolean;
    disableCheckbox?: boolean;
    checkable?: boolean;
    children?: DataNode[];
    /** Customize data info */
    [prop: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: Hey I made a reproducable [example here with data](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sun-do2wh?file=/src/App.tsx) (added to question as well) It works partially as in the selected value is shown correctly but the tree is still dots and dashes.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Answer**

In Ant design version 4.17.0 you can use `fieldNames` [Doc](https://github.com/1247748612/ant-design/blob/51e2f15d9d5762379f1bb0e7bec0ce0cdb8170a5/components/tree-select/index.en-US.md)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).